# Multiplying 1D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dimensional

If I have a 1D array in Python for example:

```
a = (10,20,30,40,50)
```

How can I multiply this by an integer for example 2 to produce:

```
b = (20,40,60,80,100)
```

I have tried:

```
b = a*2
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `a * 2` does do _something:_ `(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
>>> b = [2 * i for i in a]
>>> b
[20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
```

`a * 2` will duplicate your set:

```
>>> a = (10,20,30,40,50)
>>> a * 2
(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

Comment: @cia09mn Welcome to SO. Since this answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Tuples are immutable; use lists (`[]` instead of `()`) if you're going to want to change the contents of the actual array.

To make a new list that has elements twice those of the tuple, loop over the tuple and multiply each element:

```
b = []
for num in a:
    b.append(2*num)
```

This can be shortened to

```
b = [2*num for num in a]
```

using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Note that If you really want the final result to still be a tuple, you can use use

```
b = tuple([2*num for num in a])
```

I believe the closest thing you can get to your original syntax without using third party libraries would be

```
>>> map(lambda n: n*2, [1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

which is basically just a fancy way of saying, "take the function `f(n) = 2n` and apply if to the list `[1,2,3]`".

Comment: Tuples are not the problem here. The end result of using a list instead of a tuple is the same in terms of the elements: `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`. -1

Comment: @MattBall Totally right. (I clicked submit before enough of my answer was down.)

Comment: map function doesn't modify the list, it just returns a new one.

Comment: @MatthieuW True. I wrote that, thought about it for a second, and then realized I was being kinda stupid. Also, everyone involved in this question now has some form of the name Matthew...

Answer (score 3):

For a more natural way of working with numbers, you may want to consider [numpy](https://numpy.org/).
Using numpy, your code would like like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
b = a*2
```